# How to cast/convert form Object in an byte[] array

Tags: c#, serialization, casting, arrays

I've got a maybe simple problem, but at the moment I am not able to solve it.
I have an `Object` and I need to convert it into a `byte[]`.

```
public byte[] GetMapiPropertyBytes(string propIdentifier)
{
    return (byte[])this.GetMapiProperty(propIdentifier); //InvalidCastException 
}
```

Exception:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type
>   'System.Byte[]'. Instances of types that represent COM components
>   cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however
>   they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component
>   supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

So far so good - I've tried to serialize it, but I got another exception - NOT serializable

Could someone help me?
I need a method to convert it...

Comment: Copy the properties to a different class and serialize it.

Comment: [`PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb207517%28v=office.12%29.aspx) might help

Comment: What is the *value* of this property? what would such a byte[] look like / contain / represent?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to serialize this object and deserialize it in the client side.

If this object is not serializable, is it possible to serialize the parameters and recreate it  in client side like what web service does.

The problem is the object recreated is not the same one as before, their values are same though.

Comment: Kind of - At the moment I am try to Save an Outlook Mailitem to my hdd and read the attachments out of it.

Comment: so you want to serialize the attachments into byte array and recover it on the client side?